# Removing stubborn default styling from Wordpress custom menu

Tags: css, wordpress

I would like to remove the underline and add my own custom bullet to the list.

Please assist and also not this is not a normal menu but a custom short code used to place the menu in the div blocks.

The website is http://brainstormmarketing.agency/dev/UBG/print-and-document-division/ and when the user hovers over the colored blocks the menu appears.

[image]

I have tried removing the styling with the css classes and ids and also tried this code:

```
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:active {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: you want to remove the dashed lines or the points ?

Comment: You should be looking out for a `border` rule, something like `border-bottom: 1px dotted #000000`. You can find these styles by inspecting the element in question, then viewing the styles declared for elements in the source code you will see with the browser dev tool. Do you know how to do this? As an aside, how are you declaring your custom styles? You don't want to make any changes directly to your theme's stylesheet - rather use a 3rd party plugin for custom styles if your theme doesn't provide you with the feature to add your own without editing source files.

Comment: Yes I am using a third party plugin for my custom CSS. I am also inspecting the elements and making css changes. Thank you! I have found the border element and it has been removed

Comment: Apart from that I am also hoping to add custom bullets and remove the default bullets currently in use

Comment: This should steer you in the right direction --> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style

Answer (score 1):

The menu is just a simple unordered list ( `ul` ) . You can simply remove the default bullets with `list-style:none` , and add custom bullets with pseudo-elements `before` on the `li` . ( You can use fontAwesome icons like in the example below, or custom images, other icons etc. )

For the underline just remove the `text-decoration` on the links.

**Remember** to write specific paths like `body #content ul.menu li a` or even more specific so to overwrite the default styles

See snippet below

```css
ul.menu {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0
}

ul.menu li:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: "\f18e";
  padding: 0 5px 0 15px;
}

ul.menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

<ul id="menu-software-and-integration" class="menu">
  <li id="menu-item-1853" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1853"><a href="http://brainstormmarketing.agency/dev/UBG/print-and-document-division/software-and-integration/print-management/" itemprop="url">Print Management</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-1854" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1854"><a href="http://brainstormmarketing.agency/dev/UBG/print-and-document-division/software-and-integration/fleet-management/" itemprop="url">Fleet Management</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-1855" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1855"><a href="http://brainstormmarketing.agency/dev/UBG/print-and-document-division/software-and-integration/document-workflow/" itemprop="url">Document Workflow</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-1856" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1856"><a href="http://brainstormmarketing.agency/dev/UBG/print-and-document-division/software-and-integration/document-management/" itemprop="url">Document Management</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-1857" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1857"><a href="http://brainstormmarketing.agency/dev/UBG/print-and-document-division/software-and-integration/electronic-archival/" itemprop="url">Electronic Archival</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-1858" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1858"><a href="http://brainstormmarketing.agency/dev/UBG/cloud-integration/" itemprop="url">Cloud Integration</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-1859" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1859"><a href="http://brainstormmarketing.agency/dev/UBG/print-and-document-division/software-and-integration/mobile-print/" itemprop="url">Mobile Print</a></li>
</ul>
```